# In AES-128-ECB, if byte 15 is over 128, the padding block changes value. What's the reason for this behavior?

Tags: aes, ecb

For example, if we run this openssl command:

```
openssl aes-128-ecb -a -in <(echo -n "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA") -K "deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef"
```

The output in hex looks like:

```
block 1                          block 2
7a03acccf884d4ac38b7a2f3529806fa adfbc6ad78223f79cded6638d1d9802b
```

If I run it again and change the last byte, I get:

```
openssl aes-128-ecb -a -in <(echo -n "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa") -K "deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef"

block 1                         block 2
0c6b99d8659660bb763ca8a442948da4 adfbc6ad78223f79cded6638d1d9802b
```

Note the second block is identical.  If we decrypt just that block, we get the expected PKCS7 padding of 16 (0x10) repeated (i.e. "10101010101010101010101010101010")

```
echo "adfbc6ad78223f79cded6638d1d9802b" | xxd -r -p | openssl aes-128-ecb -d -K "deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef" -nopad | xxd -p

# gives
10101010101010101010101010101010
```

However, if we replace the last byte with a character that's 128 or over, we get a different second block. (Note € is ASCII 128)

```
openssl aes-128-ecb -a -in <(echo -n "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA€") -K "deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef" | base64 -d | xxd -p -c100

block 1                          block 2
2ec43df437eeed3a67a3390e53be7040 2999ee9243fefd95a9b3214cec97e13f
```

That second block decrypted is "82ac0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0e" which corresponds to 130, 172, and then 14 (i.e. 2 bytes of information and the rest padding).

I'm really confused about where those 2 bytes are coming from, and I can't seem to find any mention of this behavior when googling around.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (Note € is ASCII 128)

This is incorrect. Proper ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, there is no 128th element there. The Euro sign (€) is decimal 128 in some extended-ASCII encodings, most famously [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout). However, your Linux system is very likely using UTF-8. [There](https://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/%7Erichard/utf-8.cgi?input=%E2%82%AC&mode=char), the Euro sign will be encoded as three bytes `0xE282AC`:

```
~$ echo -n "€" | xxd -p
e282ac
```

Thus your input is 18 bytes long, meaning two bytes "spill over" into the second block, which will then have a padding of 14 bytes of value 14 - ie `0x0E`.

Comment: That was my issue! thank you.  When I feed the hex in via xxd the 2nd block matches.

`echo "41414141414141414141414141414180" | xxd -r -p | openssl aes-128-ecb -K "deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef" | xxd -p -c 100`

Comment: I originally came across this doing some crypto in Javascript and there is something truly terrible going on.  There are 2 euro symbols that will render fine in my browser field:    and  €.  One of them is the utf-8 valid one, the other I think is UTF-16, which if I try to copy paste into the URL bar which has I guess stricter encoding checks, it gives me the question mark block. Very strange! (edit: the first one doesn't show up on submit!)